# Combining two php lines

Tags: php

How can I combine these php lines? I'm very new with php and my goal is to hide certain navigational items from certain pages. I'd appreciate your help.
Thank you

```
<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=='/index.php'){ ?> class="hidden" <?php } ?>  <?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=='/our-menu.php'){ ?> hidden <?php } ?>
```

Comment: if\else http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use php [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) more specific the **or** `||`:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=='/index.php' || $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=='/our-menu.php'){ ?> class="hidden" <?php } ?>
```

Comment: output is different between the 2 checks

Comment: the output is the same ask him, and take of the downvote please

Comment: `class="hidden"` != `hidden`